# How to open an Excel file from a web server to the Microsoft Excel app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, blazor

Is possible to open an Excel file from a web server to the local Microsoft Excel app and save it from the Microsoft Excel app to the web server in asp.net core

Please help me with suggestions

Comment: Web Server generally does not do such a thing, because it affects the performance of the web server, so far, it does not support such an operation.

Comment: Conventionally, we download the file to the local, and then upload it to the web server after editing.

Comment: For your needs, I think [Microsoft excel online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-concept-overview) is more suitable for you. It can be edited online on the web or mobile phone, and saved in real time. Of course, [Google also has online excel](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/).

Comment: How to read complex excel sheet in asp.net core? Please help anybody